# Module '"./datasources"' has no exported member 'DbDataSource'. loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to authenticate a loopback API but I am getting Module '"./datasources"' has no exported member 'DbDataSource'.

In my application.ts I have

```
import {BootMixin} from '@loopback/boot';
import {RepositoryMixin} from '@loopback/repository';
import {RestApplication, OpenApiBuilder, ServerObject} from '@loopback/rest';
import {ServiceMixin} from '@loopback/service-proxy';
import {MySequence} from './sequence';
import {
  AuthenticationBindings,
  UsersBindings, 
  AssetsBindings,
  SubjectsBindings,
  CoursesBindings
} from './keys';
import {
  AuthenticationService,
  UsersService, 
  AssetsService, 
  CoursesService,
  SubjectsService
} from './services'

import {AuthenticationComponent} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {
  JWTAuthenticationComponent,
  SECURITY_SCHEME_SPEC,
  UserServiceBindings,
} from '@loopback/authentication-jwt';
import {DbDataSource} from './datasources';


export class AtgCodeApplication extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
  private static instance: AtgCodeApplication;
  constructor(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
    super({
      rest: {
        cors: {}
      }
    });
```

I am getting `Module '"./datasources"' has no exported member 'DbDataSource'.` with DbDataSource and also getting `Cannot find name 'ApplicationConfig'.` and `Parameter 'options' of constructor from exported class has or is using private name 'ApplicationConfig'.` in ApplicationConfig

I am using the auth procedure in https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-tutorial.html#step-1-bind-jwt-component-in-the-application as a guild.

How can I fix these errors please.

Answer (score 2):

Your `application.ts` seems a bit outdated. You might want to check with https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/examples/todo-jwt/src/application.ts as a reference.

For the `DbDataSource` issue, it is the DataSource you've created to store the User data. It might be of a different name.

Overall, you can download the latest `todo-jwt` example by running `lb4 example todo-jwt` command.